# Updating a record in JET (Access) using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, jet

I am trying to update a record in Access through VB.NET. This is my code thus far. The objective is to search a barcode, it returns the data associated with it and the user is able to change the data and save the updated data. I have everything except the update part. This is my save button with the update code. I hope I made this clear.

EDIT: Sorry. I forgot to tell you all my problem. It returns 0 rows affected, no error message.

```
 Private Sub btnEditProductSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEditProductSave.Click
    'Creates Transaction and Connection Objects
    Dim Transaction As OleDb.OleDbTransaction = Nothing
    Dim connection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = Nothing

    Try

        'Assign the Connection 
        connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(My.Settings.POS_NEWConnectionString)
        'Opens the Connection and begins the Transaction
        connection.Open()
        Transaction = connection.BeginTransaction

        Dim barcode As String = txtEditProductBarcode.Text
        Dim name As String = txtEditProductName.Text
        Dim supplier As String = cbEditProductSupplier.SelectedValue
        Dim sell As Decimal = Val(txtEditProductSellPrice.Text)
        Dim quantity As Integer = numQuantity.Value
        Dim discount As Decimal = Val(txtEditProductDiscount.Text)
        Dim department As Integer = Val(txtEditProductDepartment.Text)

        Dim SQL As String = "UPDATE PRODUCT SET ProductName = @productName, SupplierId = @supplier, SellPrice = @sellPrice, Quantity = @quantity, DiscountPrice = @discount, DepartmentNumber = @dept WHERE ProductBarcode = @barcode"

        'Creates the Command for the Transaction
        Dim CT1 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

        'Assigns a connection and transaction to a new command object
        CT1.Connection = connection
        CT1.Transaction = Transaction


        CT1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", barcode)
        CT1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productName", name)
        CT1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplier", supplier)
        CT1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sellPrice", sell)
        CT1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", quantity)
        CT1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount", discount)
        CT1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept", department)

        CT1.CommandText = SQL

        Dim number As Integer = CT1.ExecuteNonQuery

        MsgBox(number & " of row were affected")

        CT1.Dispose()

    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to say what the problem is you're having.

Comment: What is your problem with the "update part"? Does it return an error, or does it just not work?

Comment: Sorry. It doesn't give an error. It just returns 0 rows affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters in OleDb are in index order, not name.

Try it this way (barcode parameter last):

```
    CT1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productName", name)
    CT1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplier", supplier)
    CT1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sellPrice", sell)
    CT1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", quantity)
    CT1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount", discount)
    CT1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept", department)
    CT1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", barcode)
```

You also have a `BeginTransaction` but no commit.

It should look something like this:

```
Dim tx As OleDb.OleDbTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction

// blah - blah - blah

tx.Commit()
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly. I feel ashamed because I overlooked this. I have work with transactions a lot. Thanks again!